# why is position sticky not working with sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sidebar but I can't seem to make it sticky,
I need the `totalWrapper` (which includes the sidebar (red) and title ) to be sticky to the `body` AFTER we scroll past `head`

basically the black box should be sticky within the blue box, the blue box is the remaining height of the body

[image]

(the black and blue box are just added to explain the question and are legends i.e. not required in the actual code)

I feel like I'm making a rookie mistake.
can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z56f07c3/11/)

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
}

html {

  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

#totalWrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;

}

#optionsWrapper {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">head</div>
        <div id="main">
            <div style="margin:5rem">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
                ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type 
                and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
                not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
                in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 
                Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="totalWrapper">
            <div id="title">title</div>
            <div id="optionsWrapper">
                option 1<br>
                option 2<br>
                option 3<br>
                option 4<br>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I find the code and your explanation a little bit confusing. Can you post a picture or a more detailed explanation of what you want? When you say sticky, sticky to what? To the entire viewport or only within the wrapper, etc.?

Comment: @VorganHaze my bad, I did the required is it now more understandable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a little “hack” which I do not like very much since it does not feels clean and elegant (I will continue thinking on it). It gets the job done, though. I change the order of the HTML elements since the sticky part needs to come before the main content. I also clean the CSS a little bit to get rid of unnecessary code for the example to work, that way it is also easier to follow.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#stickyWrapper {
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
}

#title {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  margin-top: calc(-100vh + 50px);
  /* =====> the negative height of the stickyWrapper
            plus the positive height of the header */
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">head</div>
<div id="stickyWrapper">
  <div id="title">title</div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    option 1<br> option 2<br> option 3<br> option 4<br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
  of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
  dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
  was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
  leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
  versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: If it helps, I've managed to pinpoint the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/82yLszcw/1/ the sticky doesn't seem to work when there is a position:absolute to the element above it

Comment: Did you try the code I gave you? Did it work?

Comment: yes I did but like you yourself said it's very hacky and it might become a hassle if I start changing values so I was hoping you could come up with a better answer :)

Comment: okay I think I almost got a viable solution but the overflow is the only problem left check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/p40eza1r/1/

Comment: Just think about what you want, because you can use other methods, like grid CSS, and a more traditional layout for the page. Remember that I did the "hacky" way to avoid creating a new code completely, the point was to fix the one you provided.